# Can't choose what operating system I want to use

Tags: dual-boot

I have a laptop that came with Windows 8 preinstalled. When I turned it on for the first time, I had only C partition and a recovery partition.

I shrank the C partition in order to get some unallocated space for Ubuntu. Then I setup CD as the first boot device, and started the Ubuntu installation. The installation of Ubuntu is finished, but when I restart my computer I can't chose what operating system I want to use; instead Windows 8 starts automatically.

Comment: Try to boot from the live cd and report if you see the ubuntu partition and the installed files.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's on fast boot... here's an article about installing Ubuntu on newer computer with Windows 8 preinstalled

Here's the link.. Hope it'd help you!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for EFI partitions on your hard disk and just delete them(helped for me)

Comment: If you could expand your answer about how one should go about it. How and where should we look for EFI partition and how do I delete them?